# Blue screens and dual screens on WS2008 R2 running Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I'm a developer building silverlight apps and using Server 2008 R2 as my main operating system. I have Hyper-V running on the machine that I use to host my test O/S's and and OS for non-dev stuff (word /outlook etc). I pretty much need dual screens for my work but I have hit problems in finding a graphics card that doesn't cause a blue screen on Server 2008. The two cards I have tried so far are:
NVidia Quadro
ATI FirePro 2270

both caused blue screens a couple of times per day. If I take the graphics card out and use the motherboard VGA output I get a rock solid stable system (but then I am restricted to one screen).

I should say that for both graphics cards I used the Windows 7 drivers, because they don't give the option of WS 2008 drivers! I know that might be the problem but I can't find a graphics card that does offer WS 2008 drivers!

Can someone please recommend me a graphics card that runs WS 2008 R2 with Hyper-V.

p.s. I have installed all service packs, updates and I'm running the latest releases of the graphics drivers.

Comment: Any details on the bluescreen? Might be a problem with the MB or chipset, basically unrelated to the video card.

Answer (score 2):

> I pretty much need dual screens for my work but I have hit problems in finding a graphics card 
>   that doesn't cause a blue screen on Server 2008.

Go to a shop. Buy a 100 USD ATI card. Install drivers. Finished.

> I should say that for both graphics cards I used the Windows 7 drivers, because they don't give 
>   the option of WS 2008 drivers! I know that might be the problem but I can't find a graphics card 
>   that does offer WS 2008 drivers!

And you are painfully unaware of teh fact (as developer)  2008 R2 and Windows 7 have identical kernels ;) And thus the same driver model.

Comment: I already have bought the 100USD ATI card - the FirePro 2270 but still no joy.

Comment: Ah, no. I waqs thinking of a normal card, not a firero series. I have no problems with ATI based cards anywhere use them (and that includes some servers). Maybe your card just sucks (as in: broken). Get a replacement by warranty or try it out in another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SP1 for Win2k8 R2 installed? If not definitely install it; I had to have it for my dev setup to work correctly on my laptop w/ NVIDIA Quadro NVS to work correctly.

Regardless, to see if it's actually hyper-v causing the issues, you can [create a "no hypervisor" boot entry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry) that will disable hyper-v.

Also, see this [Microsoft connect submission](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115122515/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/527817/hyper-v-install-blue-screen-video-tdr-failure) that has a lot of details (and a [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-0x0000010e-stop-error-occurs-on-a-computer-that-uses-hybrid-graphics-in-a-heterogeneous-gpu-configuration-and-that-is-running-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-f98e5e58-23ab-546b-e0f9-95fc130d67a7)) with regard to hyper-v and blue screens in the comments.

Comment: I do have the SP1 installed - I realise that the presp1 version has a lot of hyper-v / graphics issues